# Neo4j regex in list

Tags: regex, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a list of search terms to that I would like to include in a WHERE clause with the addition of a regular expression.

I have a working single term regex in the form:

```
WHERE t.name =~ "(?i).*name.*"
```

And a query

```
Where t.name in ['Name1','Name2']
```

I would like something similar to

```
WHERE t.name in ['(?i).*name1.*', '(?i).*name2.*']
```

Comment: `WHERE t.name =~ "(?i).*name[12].*"`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `OR`:

```
WHERE t.name in '(?i).*name1.*' OR '(?i).*name2.*'
```

Or better use he regexp format for alternative matches.

```
WHERE t.name in '(?i).*(name1|name2).*'
```

you can also use expressions for the middle term:

```
WITH '(name1|name2)' as term
WHERE t.name in '(?i).*'+term+'.*'
```

Answer (score 3):

another idea (if you really have complete different regex patterns):

```
 MATCH (t) ....
 WHERE any(x in ['(?i).*name1.*', '(?i).*name2.*'] WHERE t.name =~ x)
```